# SQL: Copy records from child table to parent table, setting foreign key at the same time

Tags: sql

I have 1-to-many relationship between two tables (Product and PLProduct respectively).
This is done through foreign key PLProduct.ParentProductId which relates to Product.Id.

The question is: how can I copy (orphan) records from PLProduct to Product table, setting foreign key at the same time?

Comment: Should orphaned `PLProduct` records become their own parents in the `Product` table? If not you need to supply more info.

Comment: Thanks!

Wanted result: record in Product (parent) table, TO WHICH record in PLProduct (child) table links.

Actually, foreign key is blank in the start.

That helps?

Comment: One last clarification: Do you want a single parent record for all your orphans, or should each orphan get its own parent?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of an orphan row, a new parent row, and how the orpah is supposed to look after the update?

Comment: Thanks! By orphan i mean row with NULL FK, it is every row right now. Every single record should get it's own parent.

Example for 1 record is below.

BEFORE: Product: 0 rows. PLProduct:1 row, FK = NULL.
AFTER: Product: 1 row, ID = ID1. PLProduct:1 row, FK = ID1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two simple SQL statements should do it.  This assumes that your CHILD table has a proper PK, since we'll leverage that uniqueness to create a parent record.

```
--INSERT a parent record with a name containing the child ID
INSERT INTO Parent1
SELECT 'Child_' + CAST(ID as varchar) FROM Child1 WHERE ParentID IS NULL

--UPDATE the child table from a join to the parent table on the name field
UPDATE Child1
SET Child1.ParentID = Parent1.ID
FROM
Child1
JOIN Parent1 ON 'Child_' + CAST(Child1.ID as varchar) = Parent1.ParentName
```

I'm using SQL2000, devoid of any interesting tricks (would like to see what else turns up, though.)

Comment: Thanks, it's a solution!
But maybe there is a shorter way to do it, task looks quite simple at first.